# mod_rewrite [PT] flag returns bad request

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url, bad-request

Initially, this code was written to create **"pretty"** urls.

When using the code below, **mod_rewrite** works as it should.

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/myurl.com/httpdocs>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    php_admin_flag engine on
    php_admin_value open_basedir none
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=off
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteCond $1 ^(register|account|logout|profile|edit_profile).*$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://myurl.com/?get=$1
```

It takes any matching  url such as **https://myurl.com/register** and rewrites it as **https://myurl.com/?get=register**.  The appropriate page is found and displayed in the browser.

However, I want the original url to be passed through to the browser.  To achieve this, I added the **[PT] Flag** to my RewriteRule as shown below:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://myurl.com/?get=$1 [PT]
```

This lets **https://myurl.com/register** (same url as above) through to the browser but no longer displays the page.  Instead, it returns the following error:

```
Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Client sent malformed Host header
```

### Relevant Info:

**OS:** Linux
**Server:** Apache
**Control:** Plesk
**Directory:** /var/www/vhosts/myurl.com/conf
**File:** vhost_ssl.conf

I've searched multiple forums and articles to no avail.

**Article 1:** [Making prettier URLs with mod_rewrite](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/136) (includes use of [PT] Flag)

Does anyone have ideas on what's going on here and how to fix it?  How can I get the **"pretty"** url to display?

Comment: From what I read you should use the `R` flag, and not the `PT`. The R flag left the browser redirect to the other url. The PT flag is rarely useful, and doesn't do what you want.

Comment: Can you try changing `PT` to `P` (Proxy)

Comment: Thanks for responding. Tried both `P` and `R` flags. Both do not improve the situation.  Let me clarify the problem.  The code works fine as far as redirecting.  However, the browser is displaying the **ugly** url: `https://myurl.com/?get=$1`.  I need it to display the original **pretty** url `https://myurl.com/register`.  My research suggests that the `PT Flag` would handle that.  It doesn't.  Instead it breaks the code.  I'll try to include a link.

Comment: Have you tried changing the rule from `RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://myurl.com/?get=$1 ` to `RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /?get=$1 [L]`?

Comment: Hello Jon.  Yes, tried that too.  Didn't sleep much last night but I did finally find the solution.  Thanks for responding.  See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after two days of frustration, I finally solved the puzzle.

First I experimented with the **RewriteRule** from by changing it from:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://myurl.com/?get=$1 [P]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://myurl.com/index.php?get=$1
```

without any flags.

This produced an infinite loop whenever the rewrite was triggered.  But I noticed that the loop was happening without redirecting the url (maintaining the **'pretty url'**).  Progress!

I decided to simplify the code. I removed **'LA-U:'** from the **RewriteCond** as shown below:

```
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

That did the trick!  Thanks to those that commented.  Hope this helps someone in the future.